# Thread safety in C# lambdas

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I came across a piece of C# code like this today:

```
lock(obj)
{
  //  perform various operations
  ...

  //  send a message via a queue but in the same process, Post(yourData, callback)
  messagingBus.Post(data, () => 
  {
    //  perform operation
    ...
    if(condition == true)
    {
      //  perform a long running, out of process operation
      operation.Perform();
    }
  }
}
```

My question is this: can the callback function ever be invoked in such a way as to cause the lock(obj) to **not** be released before operation.Perform() is called?  i.e., is there a way that the callback function can be invoked on the same thread that is holding the lock, and before that thread has released the lock?

EDIT:  messagingBus.Post(...) can be assumed to be an insert on to a queue, that then returns immediately.  The callback is invoked on some other thread, probably from the thread pool.

For the operation.Perform() you can read it as Thread.Sleep(10000) - just something that runs for a long time and doesn't share or mutate any state.

Comment: It is entirely possible for `Perform` to be called after the lock has been released if the lambda expression or `Post` is asynchronous.

Comment: @vcsjones: thanks, yes, my question is the opposite - can the lock remain held whilst Perform() runs?

Comment: The question is: why would you want to have the lock be held? given that you want the `Perform()` to be in another process (which is most likely to have no conflicts, especially regarding resources and locks)

Comment: It's not my code, and I'm not suggesting I do or don't want the lock to be held.  I'm asking whether there is a possibility that it can be held whilst the long-running callback operation runs.

Comment: please give more information on the messagingBus (prism?) and the operation then

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess.

`Post` in .net generally implies that the work will be done by another thread or at another time.

So yes, it's not only possible that the lock on `obj` will be released before `Perform` is called, it's fairly likely it will happen.  However, it's not guaranteed.  Perform may complete before the lock is released.

That doesn't mean it's a problem.   The "perform various actions" part may need the lock.  messagingBus may need the lock to queue the action.   The work inside may not need the lock at all, in which case the code is thread safe.

This is all a guess because there's no notion of what work is being done, why it must be inside a lock, and what `Post` or perform does.   So the code may be perfectly safe, or it may be horribly flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Without know what messagingBus.Post is doing, you can't tell.  *If* Post invokes the delegate it is given (the lambda expression in your example) then the lock will be in place while that lambda executes.  *If* Post schedules that delegate for execution at a later time, then the lock *will not* be in place while the lambda executes.  It's not clear what the the lock(obj) is for, to lock calls to messagingBus.Post, or what...  Detailing the type (including full namespace) of the messagingBus variable would go a long way to providing better details.

Answer (score 0):

If the callback executes asynchronously, then yes, the lock may still be held when Perform() unless Post() does something specific to avoid that case (which would be unusual).

If the callback was scheduled on the same thread as the call to Post() (e. g. in the extreme example where the thread pool has only 1 thread), a typical thread pool implementation would not execute the callback until the thread finishes it's current task, which in this case would require it releasing the lock before executing Perform().

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer your question without knowing how messagingBus.Post is implemented. Async APIs typically provide no guarantee that the callback will be executed truly concurrently. For example, .Net APM methods such as FileStream.BeginRead may decide to perform the operation synchronously, in wich case the callback will be executed on the same thread that called BeginRead. Returned IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously will be set to true in this case.